# Comments Indexing with Search API

Tags: search

I'm having the issue generating the indexing for comments with Search API.
While configuring, I used the datasource `comments` and added following fields for indexing. `comment_body, cid, comment_type, created, entity_type`.

and this is the error I get.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=8926&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: parsererror
ResponseText: Error: Call to a member function toArray() on null in rdf_comment_storage_load() (line 239 of /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/core/modules/rdf/rdf.module).
```

While further investigation, I found that the line # 239 has the following code.

```
$comment->rdf_data['date'] = rdf_rdfa_attributes($created_mapping, $comment->get('created')->first()->toArray());
```

Where, `$comment->get('created')->first()` returns `NULL`, `$comment->get('created')` is the object of type `FieldItemList` which has the empty list that we can see with `$comment->get('created')->view()`

I dont know if I'm doing something wrong with configuration (prety much this is the case) or there is the issue with code, as I'm new to this CMS. I realy appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $comment->id() - get comment ID and check this comment via Drupal UI. Try resave it or delete.

Comment: `$comment->id()` returns 23

Comment: Find comment in Drupal admin interface `/admin/content/comment`, then Edit and save it (or delete).

Comment: Wow, its strange. I couldn't find the comment with id "23" in the admin interface.

Comment: you need manually call removing code on this comment #23: `$controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment');
$entities = $controller->loadMultiple([23]);
$controller->delete($entities);`